# CSS text not float left under center align div

Tags: html, css

i want my "body2" div in the center of the page and paragraph float left. but my code apply center align property on both dive.
i have used float left for para in CSS but no solution.

```
<div class="row body2" align="center">

        <div class="writing">
            <div class="date">13.01.15</div><br>
            <div class="heading">My biggest audio project ever.</div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="para">The complete setup took about 6 hours. We were extremely contended with the result taken into the account of everything is new. A late 
            </div><br><br>

            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS: i am using text-align:left to make my paragraph left align, but it show center aligned.

```
.body2
{
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.writing
{
    margin-top:64px ;
    margin-left: 88px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.date
{
    color: #716558;
    font-family: myrid Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.heading
{
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 36px;
}
.para
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    line-height: 170%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: please include your css

Comment: Please post your code on http://codepen.io or http://jsfiddle.net so we can see your code and help you to fix it.

Comment: Just a little advice. Use the `<p>` tag for paragraphs.

Comment: thanks @jojo i will follow

Comment: If you are used **align="center"** that will bring your div center and also bring your text center, to override it set the text align on your style `.body2{text-align:left}` check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvdpxLdd/)

Answer (score 0):

The `align` property acts as `text-align` in this case. Instead, you can give your `.body2` a non-auto width and apply `margin: auto;` to center the wrap: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvqfu6cx/1/)

```
.body2 {width: 70%; margin: auto;}//can also apply max-width
```

Comment: adding the width make the page static.
not responsive.

Comment: You can give it a percentage instead - that was just an example. Answer and fiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna align div in to the middle of page,

```
.body2{ width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

This will align your div in to the center of your page, change the width depend on your requirement.

to align text to left

```
.para{text-align:left;}
```

user this line, it should work good luck

Comment: adding the width make the page static.
not responsive.

Comment: @FarrukhJaved You can add then width as percentage, `width:90%;` something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can done by set the div margin auto `.body2{margin:0 auto;text-align:left}` and remove align="center" from `<div class="row body2" align="center">` that cause your text is center, or set div body2 position absolute `.body2{position:absolute; width: 300px; left: 50%; margin-left:-150px}` that style will bring your div in the center of the page, hope that will help you

Answer (score -1):

The complete setup took about 6 hours. We were extremely contended with the result taken into the account of everything is new. A late